# get the column index of a range

Tags: vba, excel

In the following subcode, I want to restrict what it does (replacing substring in hyperlinks) to a specific column. I have writen in '* what my idea is for a quick fix. But I can't seem to find **a good way to get the column value of a cell saved as a Range variable.**

```
Dim MyDoc As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range
    ...
        For Each MyCell In MyDoc.UsedRange
            If MyCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
               '* if mycell's columnnumber = 1 then
                    LinkURL = MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
                    FindPos = InStr(1, LinkURL, FindString)
                    If FindPos > 0 Then 'If FindString is found
                        ReplaceLen = Len(FindString)
                        URLLen = Len(LinkURL)
                        PreStr = Mid(LinkURL, 1, FindPos - 1)
                        PostStr = Mid(LinkURL, FindPos + ReplaceLen, URLLen)
                        NewURL = PreStr & ReplaceString & PostStr
                        MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address = NewURL 'Change the URL
                    End If
               '* End if
            End If
         Next MyCell
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply call the `Column` property:

```
If MyCell.Column = 1 Then ...
```

This is the absolute column (column A of the spreadsheet), not the first column of the range.

If you want to check if it is the first column of the range, you can first calculate it:

```
firstCol = yourRange.Cells(1, 1).Column
If MyCell.Column = firstCol Then ...
```

Comment: Correct answer for the question, but didn't help me in the specific case. But I might have found another way to fix it. Thx for the help :)